# Why does this proof on the cyclicity of a prime multiplicative group not conclude that the solutions to a polynomial biject the powers of one element?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, elementary-proofs

This argument comes from the first proof in Keith Conrad's [collection of proofs that multiplicative groups of prime-order cyclic groups contain at least one generator](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf).

The proof asks the reader to consider an element $a$ from the group $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$ which has order $d$. Now consider the polynomial $x^d=1$; it was proven in the appendix that this polynomial in our group has *at most* $d$ distinct solutions.

There are $d$ distinct powers of $a$ contained in the group and every power of $a$ is a solution to the polynomial, so now it seems clear to me that the polynomial has *exactly* $d$ solutions all of which are contained in the subgroup generated by $a$. And since every element of order $d$ must be a solution to $x^d=1$, then all elements of the group which may possibly be order $d$ are contained in the powers of $a$.

Next, those powers of $a$ are taken and filtered by their order: if the exponent has a factor of $d$ in it then the order is less than $d$, so using Euler's Totient on the number of distinct powers of $a$ we have $\phi(d)$, yielding what seems to me to be the exact number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$.

But the proof concludes here that $\phi(d)$ is *greater than or equal to* the number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$, rather than being exactly equal to.

I do not understand why this is not an equality. At first I thought that since the polynomial sets a maximum number of roots, that after filtering through the *totient* it is still not established that the polynomial may actually have all the way up to $d$ solutions — upon further thought I'm not convinced of this: the polynomial may set no minimum but the powers of $a$ *is* a set of distinct elements with size $d$ which are all solutions to the polynomial. It seems from this alone we can conclude that in this circumstance the polynomial does have *exactly* $d$ distinct solutions and that we have them all accounted for.

I'm cautious to believe that this part of the proof is erroneous, the fact that this produces an inequality is very specifically handled later in the proof, but despite going over this multiple times I cannot understand why it is necessary take this step or where the argument that $\phi(d)$ is not exactly equal to the number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$ by this point in the proof comes from.

Comment: Language point:  there can be only one unique thing; if you have multiple different things of the same type (like powers of $a$), then they are *distinct*, not unique. \\ Theorem 2.1 shows, as you expect, that $N_p(d) = \varphi(d)$ if $N_p(d)$ is positive.  The point is that, *a priori*, there could be some $d$ dividing $p - 1$ with $N_p(d) = 0$, in which case we have $N_p(d) < \varphi(d)$. \\ This is a good question, but for MSE, not MO.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Was not thinking generally enough for $N_p(d)$ (only considering it in the case of a singular $a$ after the assumption was made. My bad about  using the wrong math board - didn't realize there were two.

Comment: @LSpice I have made the post on MSE if you would like to post your answer there. It did help - and I wonder if the proof could be made significantly shorter if an argument about the number of elements of order $d$ equaling zero is impossible could be made in short order. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399919/why-does-this-proof-on-the-cyclicity-of-a-prime-multiplicative-group-not-conclud

Comment: @LSpice concerning your usage remark about distinct vs. unique, try telling that to the people who refer to the number of “unique viewers” of a video on YouTube. 

Comment: @KConrad, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417826/why-does-this-proof-on-the-cyclicity-of-a-prime-multiplicative-group-not-conclud#comment1137209_417826), the number of unique visitors used to be 1, but, sadly, someone else watched, so it is now 0. 